# Does MvvmCross work in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio, icommand

I'm having a time getting a straight answer on this, I've done a lot of searches and reading, and tried a lot of stuff.  It sometimes sounds possible and other times only sounds possible by doing linking and what-not, which is something I'm trying to avoid.  I'm a big fan of PCLs.

I've created a solution using Visual Studio 2012, Xamarin, and MvvmCross which works great, I can deploy to an iOS device, a Droid device, Windows --- what have you.  Visual Studio can build working applications that I can deploy to specific platforms.

However, I was informed recently that our company requires that when we go to deploy, the code must be built on a Mac using Xamarin Studio by their build server.  So since then I've been working on trying to open and build everything using Xamarin Studio, and I'm close, but the infamous ICommand issue is my final hurdle.

Is there, or is there not, a way to get ICommands and the System.Windows library ported in correctly in Xamarin Studio?  Am I truly stuck until Xamarin releases their PCL support?

Answer (score 5):

> Does MvvmCross work in Xamarin Studio?

Yes

To prove it:

- quite a few of the N+1 videos show this being used.
- lots of the samples (all of the non-nuget ones) build and run from XS

> Is there, or is there not, a way to get ICommands and the System.Windows library ported in correctly in Xamarin Studio?

The problem currently is that on the Stable branch, the xamarin compiler doesn't like the PCL import of `MvxCommand` which inherits from `ICommand`

A hard way around this problem is:

- rewrite the Xamarin tools to support PCLs - this is what the brilliant, lovely and very clever Xamarin monkeys are currently doing :)

Or... a slightly easier way around this problem is:

- replace the nuget references to the PC-built libraries with references to the Xamarin-Mac-built libraries instead - these Xamarin-Mac-built libraries are available in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Binaries/

Or... a really easy way around the problem is:

- instead of using `MvxCommand` in your view models, just implement your own `MyCommand` class to implement `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` (e.g. use the implementation at http://www.lines-davies.net/blog/?p=24)

> Am I truly stuck until Xamarin releases their PCL support?

I don't think so - but where you do hit problems:

- please do come back to sites like StackOverflow with one specific problem at a time - this site is great for finding solutions one at a time :)
- talk to Xamarin support - they are generally very helpful in trying to resolve issues.

What's more, even if you were stuck waiting... then Xamarin have already released their PCL support to the Alpha channel - so the wait is almost over already :)

Comment: Awesome, Stuart, thanks much for the very good, clear answer.  Appreciate your fast responses.  I can't wait for Xamarin to get PCL support out there.

Comment: No worries - if you do just create your own Command then I think it should work (it does for me!). If you do hit other issues, then please do write more questions. If you can, please do also include some low-level techie details. e.g. on this one, I actually had to think about what the 'infamous ICommand bug' was. Much easier if you can include a description and some error messages - that detail will also help in a few months time when there's a totally different ICommand problem causing issues ;)

Comment: Stuart, the issue is Xamarin Studio stable appears to be an implementation of .NET 4.0, and ICommand appears to be a 4.5 feature (it doesn't show up until I change my target framework to 4.5), and therefore doesn't recognize an ICommand.  So I can't implement System.Windows.Input.ICommand specifically, so to speak.  Are you saying I need to create my own ICommand to mimick Microsoft's ICommand interface and then implement that interface in my own "MvxCommandEx" class that mimicks your MvxCommand class?

Comment: Yes - "•instead of using MvxCommand in your view models, just implement your own MyCommand class to implement System.Windows.Input.ICommand (e.g. use the implementation at http://www.lines-davies.net/blog/?p=24)" - just hack in your own icommand

Comment: Well, no luck getting this to work with the 3rd option (custom ICommand).  I created my own ICommand interface, very simple, then created my own MvxCommandEx which implemented my fake ICommand interface, and refactored those changes throughout my view models, and it liked it on build.  But come run-time, it just doesn't do anything.  It appears to be constructing all the MvxCommandEx's, but when I click a button which has been bound to that model member, it doesn't do anything, it's not invoking the method that's been tied to that command... :(  Not exactly sure where to go next.

Comment: Btw, I was able to get it working by unbinding the View to the ViewModel and then on the btnLogin.Click, calling the ViewModel command directly --- ie. "((LoginViewModel)ViewModel).LogIn.Execute(null);"........ but this method is very un-MVVM-y.

Comment: You're writing too much in comments here - if your Command doesn't work then post a question about it. Sorry - no-one can really help you here in this 'comment small print'